# Mongodb aggregation $project get array position element field value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("560dcd15491a065d6ab1085c"),
    "title" : "example title",
    "views" : 1,
    "messages" : [
        {
            "authorId" : ObjectId("560c24b853b558856ef193a3"),
            "authorName" : "Karl Morrison",
            "created" : ISODate("2015-10-02T00:17:25.119Z"),
            "message" : "example message"
        }
    ]
}
```

Project:

```
$project: {
    _id: 1,
    title: 1,
    views: 1,
    updated: '$messages[$messages.length-1].created' // <--- ReferenceError: $messages is not defined
}
```

I am trying to get the last elements created value from the array inside of the document. I was reading the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) but this specific task has fallen short.

I've learnt it has to do with [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation). However doesn't state how to get the last element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot just extract properties or basically change the result from a basic `.find()` query beyond simple top level field selection as it simply is not supported. For more advanced manipulation you can use the aggregation framework.

However, without even touching `.aggregate()` the [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) projection operator gets you most of the way there:

```js
db.collection.find({},{ "messages": { "$slice": -1 } })
```

You cannot alter the structure, but it is the last array element with little effort.

Until a new release ( as of writing ) for MongoDB, the aggregation framework is still going to need to [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array in order to get at the "last" element, which you can select with the [`$last`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) grouping accumulator:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$messages" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "title": { "$last": "$title" },
        "views": { "$last": "$views" },
        "created": { "$last": "$messages.created" }
   }}
])
```

Future releases have `$slice` and `$arrayElemAt` in aggregation which can handle this directly. But you would also need to set a variable with `$let` to address the dot notated field:

```js
    [
        { "$project": {
            "name": 1,
            "views": 1,
            "created": {
                "$let": {
                    "vars": {
                        "message": { 
                            "$arrayElemAt": [
                                { "$slice": [ "$messages", -1 ] },
                                0
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "in": "$$message.created"
                }
            }
        }}
    ]
```

Comment: @KarlMorrison Yes I can read. But it's also pretty clear it may not be the best option, which is why there is also an alternate solution suggested.

Comment: I like how you informed me of the unwind, however I do (unfortunately) need to manipulate the document further later on!

Comment: @KarlMorrison What you need to understand here is that your question asks for a field property from the array and from the last member of the array. This is what the answer tells you to do. If you want to keep copies of things then either copy the array field beforehand or `$push` back content to the array. There is no other way to presently do this. The next version of MongoDB will include a `$slice` operator for use with the aggregation framework. You also only get to ask the question you asked, and no other questions in a single question.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around your answer, I'll get back to you :)

Comment: @KarlMorrison It's really quite simple. The sort of notation your are trying is not basically valid. Proper indexed "dot notation" nor the `$slice` operator shown originally are supported in the aggregation framework at all. So you presently need to deconstruct the array to get the `$last` element from it. Or as I said originally, just live with what you get from `$slice`, as it's not all that bad. Future MongoDB 3.2 ( or whatever version ) syntax shown as well.

Comment: @KarlMorrison Sorry that should have said "not supported in aggregation" which of course makes more sense. Typo too late to edit.

Comment: It's ok mate! I'm trying to implement it now :) I'm getting however an error: `MongoError: exception: invalid operator '$arrayElemAt'`

Comment: @KarlMorrison **Future Release** Which it says quite clearly, so it is not supported yet. Use the statement with `$unwind`. You have no other choice.

Comment: Haha oh sorry man! I'll save the code for later. I'll check the unwind and get back immediately!

Comment: Indeed it worked, thank you :) Is there any advantage/disadvantage over using one or the other?

Comment: @KarlMorrison If you have other aggregation operations then you really have no choice. Naturally, processing `$unwind` and needing to `$group` back the document is a good deal of overhead. Better to [ask additional questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you have broader details.